# How can I make two different events trigger the same action with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

As a Python beginner I've been trying to write a simple login module that can be utilized by other Python programs I've written in order to restrict who can open the program. I'm only writing this with the purpose of learning and not actually using it but I need some help.

My issue is that once the credentials are entered, I can only make my Enter key OR my Mouse-One trigger the "login" function. I'm a little stuck trying to figure out how to make both Enter AND Mouse click valid events to trigger the function.

Here is what I have so far. Currently only the Enter key will trigger "login":

```
from tkinter import *


def mainlogin():

    # Root
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Login")
    root.geometry("240x110")
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)

    # Globals
    global allow_entry
    allow_entry = False

    # Login Credentials 
    my_username = 'abcd'
    my_password = '1234'

    # Login Function

    def login(event):
        if my_username == username.get() and my_password == pswd.get():
            allow_entry = True
            root.quit()
        else:
            allow_entry = False
            wrong_input = Label(root, text="Wrong username or password!")
            wrong_input.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

    # Enter Key Bind
    root.bind("<Return>", login)

    # Login entry widgets
    username = Entry(root)
    username.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    pswd = Entry(root, show="*")
    pswd.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

    # Buttons

    login_button = Button(root, text="Login", command=login)
    login_button.pack()

    ### MAIN LOOP ###
    root.mainloop()


def quit_login():
    allow_entry = False
    root.quit()


def disable_event():
    pass

### NAME == MAIN ###

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainlogin()
```

Comment: What's wrong with using the same `root.bind...` for the additional button you want? Not that the `login` function will work anyway; you're reassigning to a variable that's outside of the function's scope.

Comment: OP's description is misleading.  What he/she means is that the `login()` function can be triggered by `Enter` key, but not by *clicking `Login` button*.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default argument for the mouse button event:

```
    def login(event=None):
       if not event: 
           print('>> Button')
       else:
           print('>> Return')
       ......
```